# Looking for fusion table map info window to be hyperlink of each address in google maps

Tags: html, google-fusion-tables

I haven't been able to find a clear answer for this problem.  Below is what my current code is, after trying multiple things.

```html
<b>Address:</b><a href="http://maps.google.com"target="{Address}">{Address}</a><br>
```

I found some helpful information here as well https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-fusion-tables/nGIyV5C5K-A

But, as of now, I can only get the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNXPF.png)to take me to Google Maps, can someone help point me in the right direction of how to make it specific to each address?

-any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<b>Address:</b><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/{Address}" target="_blank">{Address}</a><br>
```

Your original URL structure wasn't correct to begin with - the {Address} variable should have been a part of the URL instead of the target. "Target" specifies if the link will open in the current window, a new window, a new tab, etc. And I changed the URL from "maps.google.com" to "google.com/maps/place/" because that's the URL structure of Google Maps (the other URL is just a redirect).

Hope this helps!

---

**Edit:**
If there are multiple fields that your address is broken down into, then you need to add those fields to the URL as well. I live in a city that has the same address as the White House (1600 Pennsylvania Ave). If I don't include the city and state for the White House at 1600 Pennsylvania Ave, Washington, DC, it will redirect to the closest address to me (in Kansas). See example below:

```
<b>Address:</b><a href="https://www.google.com/maps/place/{Address}, {City}, {State} {Zip}" target="_blank">{Address}</a><br
```

Here's a [sample table](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1O38hIrlX41GL5XEP9ZrRQnwpUfYDPHOjdbJwyyRV) with example layouts I've provided above in a card.

Comment: Thank for the response. I am still unable to get that to work.  It doesn't seem to reconize {Address} while it is in quotes.  Because it will work when I code it for a specific address.  Is there a way to append {Address} at the end of the href?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a second example and a sample table you can view

Comment: My initial answer should be adequate to do what you require. I have several  Fusion Tables that utilize a location link as an address or GPS coordinates and they all function correctly. The issues I think you may have could lie in how the address is formatted within your Address field. Another possibility is how your html is missing a space between your href="...{Address}" and the target="_blank" properties. My example table in my answer should point you in the right direction.